# C borra valor de la variable cuando es pasada como parametro de un metodo

Tags: c, variables

estoy haciendo un programa en lenguaje C, el problema es que tengo una variable de tipo int y cuando la paso como parametro, C me la borra.

```
char letra, name[] = "";
int compuesto;
compuesto = Es_Compuesto(nom, lon);//RETORNA UN INT
if (compuesto != 0){
    strncpy(name, nom, compuesto);//AQUI SE CAMBIA DE VALOR
    if (strlen(name) != compuesto) {
        name[compuesto] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Podrian decirme que es lo que esta sucediendo y como podria solucionarlo. Gracias

Comment: Qué variable es la que borra el valor?

Comment: "C" no borra nada, tu lógica la esta borrando, debes indicar que es lo que obtienes, y que es lo que deseas obtener.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí declaras un array de tamaño 1 (solo admite un caracter):

```
char name[] = "";
```

Y aquí almacenas una cadena en dicho array:

```
strncpy(name, nom, compuesto);
```

El contenido de `compuesto` se borra porque la función `strncpy` está escribiendo más allá de la memoria reservada para `name`, por lo que irremediablemente empezará a pisar memoria que pertenece a otras variables.

Plantéate darle a `name` un tamaño lo suficientemente grande como para trabajar sin problemas:

```
char name[100] = "";
```

Por cierto. En esta parte del código:

```
if (strlen(name) != compuesto) {
    name[compuesto] = '\0';
```

No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que pretendes... la función `strncpy` ya se encarga de finalizar la cadena con un caracter nulo independientemente de la longitud de la cadena, luego esta operación es totalmente innecesaria al menos tal y como está planteada.